# Laravel Eloquent Query to return count of grouped objects

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am working with laravel 5.1 and can't get this query to work. I have a places table, with a column county. I want to group by county and count how many of each country are in the table. I have a Place model for the places table but cannot figure out the query builder for this one.

A query that works is:
select county, count(*) from places group by county

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (Add a use statement for `DB` or use `\DB`):

```
  $result = DB::table('places')
  ->select('county', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->groupBy('county')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head does something like this work:

```
User::where('county')->count();
```